# Don't indent wrapped lines in a itemized environment

Tags: indentation, itemize, enumitem

I am trying to prevent a wrapped line from indenting within an `item` of an `itemize` environment, like so:

[image: Non-Indented text after a bullet]

Unfortunately, `itemize produces this:

[image: Indented text after a bullet]

How can I make `itemize` produce the first thing? I'm guessing `enumitem` is involved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `enumitem` package to achieve this. It defines a convenience key `wide` which help to set your items to look like paragraphs. See page 8 of the documentation for more details.

You did not mention whether you wanted the label to be indented as well, so I have taken the liberty to provide solutions for both. Notice the extra options if you do not want label indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.

    % With label indent
    \begin{itemize}[wide]
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
    \end{itemize}

    % Without label indent
    \begin{itemize}[wide,labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt]
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Example output**

[image]

Comment: For the 2nd version, it's simpler to specify `wide=0pt`. Needless to specify `labelindent=0pt`.